# XAML Coding Guidelines

Tags: .net, xaml, coding-style

There is a plenty coding guidelines/standards available for c# language. However I couldn't find anything "official" regarding XAML. I'm particularly interested in naming conventions of the visual elements, but something about formatting would be also useful. At the moment my XAML files look like a big soup of tags, not really human readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this [blog entry](http://paulstovell.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/xaml-and-wpf-coding-guidelines/) ([wayback machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20100629015119/http://groups.google.com.au/group/wpf-disciples/web/wpf-and-xaml-coding-guidelines?) to google group posting) on WPF and XAML conventions for you.  It is not the most complete, but gives you some ideas.  With regard to visual elements, I actually stuck with the naming convention I use for asp.net and windows forms.  If it is a new element in WPF, I usually just think of what the best prefix would be, for example MediaElement could be me.